# AG-Grid Angular: Using multi filter(Text filter and Set Filter) on a column in Server-side row model with partial store not working

Tags: ag-grid, ag-grid-angular

AG-Grid : I am using Server side model with partial store. I want to apply multi filter(Text filter and Set Filter) on a column. I did it using below code.

```
filter: 'agMultiColumnFilter',
        filterParams: {
          filter: [
            {
              filter: 'agTextColumnFilter',
              filterParams: {
                defaultOption: 'startWith'
              }
            },
            {
              filter: 'agSetColumnFilter',
              filterParams: {
                values: this.getFilterList,
                refreshValuesOnOpen: true
              }
            },
          ]
        },
```

How the values are being passed? Explained below.

```
filterParams: {
  values: this.getFilterList,
  refreshValuesOnOpen:  true
}
```

**this.getFilterList** will fetch the values for the set filter by making an async call.
However, this is throwing below error when I click on filter icon in UI(shown below).

**Error: ag-Grid: Set Filter cannot initialise because you are using a row model that does not contain all rows in the browser. Either use a different filter type, or configure Set Filter such that you provide it with values**

[Set Filter Error when used with Multi filter in SSRM](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yqOa1.png)

I tried using the setFilter code separately(just to check whether I am doing it right) and it is working as expected but not with multi-filter. Is there something I am missing on?

We have another page where we are using Client side model and there Multi-filter works as expected without any error.

Can someone help me to sort out this issue?

Answer (score 1):

I just ran into the same issue today while setting up `agMultiColumnFilter`. The reason was a typo inside the `filterParams` property; the correct top-level key is named `filters` rather than `filter`:

```js
        filter: 'agMultiColumnFilter',
        filterParams: {
          filters: [
            {
              filter: 'agTextColumnFilter',
              filterParams: {
                defaultOption: 'startWith'
              }
            },
            {
              filter: 'agSetColumnFilter',
              filterParams: {
                values: this.getFilterList,
                refreshValuesOnOpen: true
              }
            },
          ]
        },
```

Reference in official docs: https://www.ag-grid.com/javascript-data-grid/filter-multi/#multi-filter-parameters